# Implementation error in ISE for a Virtex-5 board

Tags: licensing, verilog, xilinx, xilinx-ise

I'm using a Xilinx Virtex-5 version XC5VLX110T in ISE project navigator 14.6  to test a simple code but it always give implementation design error:

> ERROR:Security:12 - No 'xc5vlx110t' feature version 2013.06 was
>    available (-15),
>   ERROR:Map:258 - A problem was encountered attempting
>    to get the license for this    architecture.

[this is it's Design proprieties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w65IB.png)

The code is:

```
module compare(clk ,x,y
    );
input x,clk;

output reg  y;


always  @(posedge clk)

begin 


y= x+1'b1;
end 
endmodule
```

Comment: Not all device sizes are included in the webpack license.

Comment: okey,but how to get full license or the device license ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends ...

First, have a look into the Xilinx license manager to see what's supported and what's not.

Some development boards are sold with a "node locked license". If so, your package should contain a serial for the registration process on Xilinx.com. Then you can download your personal, board specific license and register it in ISE.

Otherwise you'll need a normal/full license, which is quite expensive. For development purposes, you can change the device for ex. to `XC5VLX50T-1FFG1136` (Virtex-5 LX50T from ML505 board) this one should supported by the webpack license. All implementation steps will work, but programming, because it's the false size and pinout.